# How to write the order of key-value pairs in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write programs for the following problems.

a. The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is unpredictable but sometimes it makes sense to sort them by key. Write a function that takes a dictionary and prints the entries of the dictionary in alphabetical order. Use sorted() to sort the entries in the dictionary.

For instance, given the input `{'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}`

the program should print

```
Age: 52
City: Napier
Name: Betty
```

This is the code I tried:

```py
Entry = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}

for alphabet in Entry:
    Value = Entry['Name', 'City', 'Napier']

print(Value)
```

Do I have to sort key-value pairs by key first by using sorted?

So does it go like this?

I wonder if I am on the right track.

```py
Entry = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}

for alphabet in Entry:
    Key_Name = sorted(Entry)
    Value = Entry['Name', 'City', 'Napier']

print(Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default iterator of a dictionary returns an iterator over the keys, so `sorted` will return a sorted array of keys, which you can iterate over:

```py
entry = {'Name':'Betty', 'City': 'Napier', 'Age':52}
keys = sorted(entry)
for key in keys:
    print(f"{key}: {entry[key]}")
```

This code uses [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).